# Retrieving OS Platform .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm retrieving the operating system platform with .NET Core with [system.runtime.interopservices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.InteropServices/)
I have created the code below and was wondering if there was any other way that I could improve it since I haven't been able to get a switch statement to work in the OperatingSystem class.

```
/// <summary>
/// Operating System Class
/// For Retrieving The OS
/// Platform.
/// AE : 9/08/2018
/// </summary>
class OperatingSystem
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Operating System Platforms.
    /// </summary>
    public enum OSPlatform
    {
        Windows,
        OSX,
        Linux,
        Not_Supported
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return Operating System
    /// </summary>
    public static OSPlatform GetPlatform
    {
        // Switch Statement Not Compatitable
        get
        {
            if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform.Windows))
            {
                return OSPlatform.Windows;
            }
            else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform.OSX))
            {
                return OSPlatform.OSX;
            }
            else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform.Linux))
            {
                return OSPlatform.Linux;
            }
            else
            {
                return OSPlatform.Not_Supported;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The class is being called like this,

```
static void Main()
{
    switch (OperatingSystem.GetPlatform)
    {
        case OperatingSystem.OSPlatform.Windows:
            Console.WriteLine("Goto Windows Class");
            break;
        case OperatingSystem.OSPlatform.OSX:
            Console.WriteLine("Goto OSX Class");
            break;
        case OperatingSystem.OSPlatform.Linux:
            Console.WriteLine("Goto Linux Class");
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("OS Not Supported");
            break;
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: I have a question: why have you created another enum that is virtually exactly the same as the core's one instead of using the original one?

Comment: because its not a constant value

Comment: @t3chb0t also from what I can see OSPlatform is a struct and not an enum.

Comment: So you need a constant value? Could you specify your use case in more detail? Is this only because you _like_ `switch`es? I find it's a bad idea to duplicate those values without a very good reason.

Comment: yeah it just comes down to me preferring switch es over if's once they get past a certian amount of uses and are too long

Comment: Have you considered using a value object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Review

- Don't use underscores in enum values `NotSupported`
- The enum value with integer value 0 represents its default value; I would make this `NotSupported` in order to avoid some bias
- `GetPlatform` is a method name; prefer `Platform` as property name
- Since the platform won't change while your program is running, consider using a `Lazy` to retrieve the platform once.

#### Don't like if-statements?

Let's first refactor the enum to match aforementioned conventions:

```
public enum OSPlatform
{
    NotSupported,
    Windows,
    OSX,
    Linux,
}
```

We could then use a `Lazy`:

```
 static readonly Lazy<OSPlatform> platform = new Lazy<OSPlatform>(GetPlatform, true);
 public static OSPlatform Platform => platform.Value;
```

And refactor the intitial method using a helper generator using a simple `ValueTuple` to avoid the boiler-plate if-statements.

```
private static IEnumerable
    <(OSPlatform Platform, RuntimeOSPlatform RuntimePlatform)?> EnumeratePlatforms() 
{
    yield return (OSPlatform.Windows, RuntimeOSPlatform.Windows);
    yield return (OSPlatform.OSX, RuntimeOSPlatform.OSX);
    yield return (OSPlatform.Linux, RuntimeOSPlatform.Linux);
}

private static OSPlatform GetPlatform()
{
    return EnumeratePlatforms().FirstOrDefault(p 
       => RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(p.Value.RuntimePlatform))?.Platform ?? default;
}
```

I've created an alias to avoid redundant namespace code:

```
using RuntimeOSPlatform = System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform;
```

If you want to have some fun, you could refactor this solution to use `Expression` and some reflection to avoid creating hard-coded tuples.

Comment: You're writing answers at a gruelling pace :-O I cannot keep up reading them so there's a small voting lag lol

Comment: @t3chb0t Yeah I checked you weren't only for 27 minutes o_O Please keep up :/ lol :p

Comment: I'll try but my tokenizer is driving me crazy :P I have more ideas so I'll post a new question soon; I'm adding a context to it and... no more spoilers ;-]

Comment: I see you have enough green internet points for today... let's save some for tomorrow.

Comment: This is a really nice answer, thank you :)